# Moving panel from crawl space

Tags: electrical

I’m wanting to move my main electric panel from my tall crawl space to a hallway that leads upstairs but not sure if it’s allowed it has 41 in of space in the front it’s the only good wall for it to go because the exterior wall is a kitchen to a bathroom it will only be 7 ft from the meter base that sits behind bathroom wall.
I’ve replace panels on exterior walls but haven’t moved one [image]

Comment: I take it you plan to use the old panel box as a splice/junction box?

Comment: Since you’re *already* storing stuff there, it’s a bad location. Because who’s kidding who, that stuff will go right back there before the paint’s even dry.  Can’t store stuff in front of a panel. The best way to avoid that is choose panel locations that are not suitable for storage, i.e. that face natural pathways.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to store your vacuum, etc. elsewhere if following the letter of code.

Working space for a panel: not to be used for storage, can be used for passage (ie hallway is good, closet/clutter is not) Clear space, 30 inches wide (with the panel in it, but need not be centered in it), 36 inches out, 78 inches high.

Comment: See more detail & code cites about working space here https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/25934/18078